# Prevent NaN from being pressed first or twice

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a calculator in JavaScript and want to prevent users from pressing a NaN (like divide, plus etc. i.e. only press a number first) and to prevent a Nan from being pressed twice e.g. don't allow divide to be pressed twice. How could I go about doing this?

Here is my code:

```
var result = ""; //must be a string so it concatenates rather than adds

function calc(digit){

    if (digit == "ans"){
        var prevResult = result;
        result = prevResult;
        $("#resultBox").append("Ans");
    }
    else if (digit == "sum"){
        $("#resultBox").val(eval(result));
    }
    else if (digit == "clear"){
        location.reload();
    }
    else{
      result += digit; 
      $("#resultBox").val(result);  
    }
}
```

here is an example of a few buttons in my HTML:

```
<button class="large" type="button" value="divide"onclick=calc("/")>/</button>

<button class="small" type="button" value="1" onclick=calc(1)>1</button>
```

Comment: Store the last pressed button in a variable and check this. If it's empty, then it's the first button that is pressed, if the variable has a value you check whether it's a number or a operator and based on that you do something.

Comment: `result = prevResult;` seems redundant. `location.reload();` is blunt, why aren't inputs in a form so you can just do `form.reset()`?

Answer (score 0):

change first else section to

```
else if (digit == "sum"){
    if ( result.length > 0 )
    {
        $("#resultBox").val(eval(result));
    }
}
```

similarly, for divide and plus, check if the last character is a number

```
if ( result.length > 0 && !isNaN(result.slice(-1) )
{
   result += digit; 
}
```